# How to complete an action after a Courtine is done

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a coroutine that decreases an image fill amount until it equals 0. Once it equals 0 I want to set a variable to true. Then from another class, I want to check if this variable is true. If it is then destroying the said object.

**Where coroutine is being called**

```
public int GatherResource(int currentAmount)
    {
        currentAmount += currentAmount + amount;
        gatherCooldown();

        return currentAmount;
    }

   public void gatherCooldown()
{
    Debug.Log("Start courtine");
    cooldown.resourceCooldown();

    if (cooldown.resourceDestroyed)
    {
        destoryResource();
    }
}

public void destoryResource()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

**Courtine**

```
public bool isCooldown;
    public Image imageCooldown;
    public float cooldown = 5;
    public bool resourceDestroyed = false;
    private IEnumerator CooldownRoutine()
    {
        isCooldown = true;

        while (imageCooldown.fillAmount <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Image:" + imageCooldown.fillAmount);
            imageCooldown.fillAmount -= 1 / cooldown * Time.deltaTime;

            CheckIfResourceIsDestroyed();

            yield return null;
        }

    }

    public void resourceCooldown()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CooldownRoutine());
    }

    public bool CheckIfResourceIsDestroyed()
    {
        if (imageCooldown.fillAmount == 0)
        {
            resourceDestroyed = true;
        }

        return resourceDestroyed;
    }
```

**PlayerController. This is where the I call the class that calls the courutine**

*DoubleClick() is a method that detects if the user has double clicked the mouse*

```
void CheckIfResource(RaycastHit hit)
    {
        //Checks if the player has clicked a resource
        //Creates an instance of ResourceSource
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Resource") && DoubleClick())
        {
            resource = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ResourceSource>();
            clickResource(resource);

        }
    }

void clickResource(ResourceSource resource)
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(resource.GetPositon(), gameObject.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("Dist:" + dist);

        if (dist <= 5)
        {
            moving = false;
            Vector3 playerPos = transform.position;
            woodResource += resource.GatherResource(woodResource);
            resource.destoryResource();
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: One potential option would be to pass a callback (e.g.: a `Action`)  to the coroutine that it invokes after the `while` loop terminates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `IEnumerator` and put the `boolean` you want to activate after it is finished at the end of your function.

**Example:**

```cs
private IEnumerator CooldownRoutine() {
    ...
    resourceDestroyed = true;
}
```

Comment: This somewhat works however i still have to run the courtine again.

Comment: @Madmitten What do you mean you have to run the coroutine again?

Comment: You mean you'll use the coroutine multiple times?

Comment: added edits above. Sorry if im explaining this badly

Comment: @Madmitten If i understand it correctly you are slowly fading wood to make it uncollactable for a certain time. Could you further explain when and why exactly do you want to remove the gameobject you just faded? To remove it completly from the game because it shouldn't be interacted with anymore?